# Validate child components / guards

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my Angular 2 application I have several components for configuring several settings (I will call them "child components" from now on) and the module's main component that is routed to and that uses these child components. I make use of reactive (model-driven) forms, so each child component has its own form (and `FormGroup`).

Saving will be done with one save button on the main component. My first problem is how do I figure out, from this main component, whether all of its child components are valid? I already have figured out I can use `@ViewChild` in order to access my child components and it works.

1. Is is a valid purpose for `@ViewChild` or just a dirty hack and there is a better solution for this?
2. Another approach would be to store `myFormGroup.valid` inside the service and update it within `myFormGroup.statusChanges.subscribe(...)`. Has the valid property already changed when this event fires? (The description *"Emits an event every time the validation status of the control is re-calculated"* doesn't make this clear for me).
3. Is it legitimate to use the `@ViewChild` for the dirty-detection for the `CanDeactivate` guard?